# How to integrate mastercard gateway to do payment using token?

Tags: mastercard

I am trying to integrate mastercard payment gateway on my website. I have generated a token (by sending the card details). Now I want to deduct the amount from the card using this token. I have tried with `apiOperation` as 'PAY' but getting the error

> Value  'PAY' is invalid. Pay request not permitted for this merchant

- URL: [https://test-bank-site.com/api/rest/version/59/merchant/{merchantid}/order/{ordrid}/transaction/{transactionid}](https://test-bank-site.com/api/rest/version/59/merchant/%7Bmerchantid%7D/order/%7Bordrid%7D/transaction/%7Btransactionid%7D)
- Method: PUT
- Payload:

  ```json
  {
    "apiOperation":"PAY",
    "sourceOfFunds": {
      "type":"SCHEME_TOKEN",
      "token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "order": {
      "amount":1,
      "currency":"QAR"
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need to contact your financial institution or acquirer bank and ask him to enable AUTO CAPTURE privilege for your merchant.
also order certainty must be FINAL in this case .